# Receiving messages in background - asynctask or service

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

I am writing a messenger app. When the app is started (and maybe in the future at boot time without UI), a background process should launch and receive the new messages. If a new message is received, it should show notification.

What should I use: **AsyncTask** or **Service**?

I think whatsapp uses Service.

Comment: Whatsapp is using push Notifications. Same way you need to do in order to get the notifications.

Comment: no no. the app is connected all the time to the chatserver.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTasks should be used for short lived tasks, like downloading file (small), processing data files, sending data to server. Services are for tasks which lifetime is a lot longer, as you say your app is all the time connected to server. So, you should use Service. You will have to maintain you own thread inside service for your networking tasks. You of course can create notifications from service.

Using service also causes that its less likely for your app to be killed by system if it is low on resources. Its good for such background app to keep notification with information that your app is working, also to make your app even less likely to be killed use foreground service (Service.startForeground() method).